# manage the APIs between scoring webpage and the VMIX App

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, api

I am working to build a scoring system for Referee to have full control to manage the scores.
however, the scores will be viewed on a large screen using the vmix app(it is a streaming app similar to OBS)
my webpage will manage all scores and then should send the scores to the vmix to view them on the screen.
So, I want the proper way to manage the APIs between the webpage and the vmix app
(NOTICE: vmix app provides the required data to make the connection)

Here is the needed data provides by vmix
(http://127.0.0.1:8088/API/?Function=SetText&Input=877bb3e7-58bd-46a1-85ce-0d673aec6bf5&SelectedName=Headline.Text&Value=Hello)
(the attributes that written between brackets that what vmix provide)

I wrote my HTML code and I used the GET method in jquery

In conclusion, what do you think the proper way to have connection betweenthe webpage and the vmix app, and the proper languages to do that.

Here is jQuery Code:
$( document ).ready(function() {

```
    $.get("http://192.168.100.147:8088/" , function(data)
    {
      var inputvalue1 = 0
      var inputvalue2 = 0
      var Input
      var SelectedName
      var Value

     $("#B1" ).click(function() 
    {
      inputvalue1=inputvalue1+15;
      $("#result_1").text(inputvalue1);

       $.get('http://192.168.100.147:8088/',"SetText","c9a3e111-6ffd-4e1f-ab9b-10f0bba0b8b5","SelectedName=ScoreBoard.xaml","Value=100", function (SetText)
      {  
        alert("Done")
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use datasource feature on Title Editor...
Also in Title editor you can use JSON
[This is the Window of DataSource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwtVW.png)

[List of Supported Datasource Vmix have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBxcP.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33442253)